# How to overcome with webflow logic flow problem?

Tags: mailchimp, webflow

I have set API token to transfer a data of form to mailchimp and when i test flow in webflow logic flow it is successful and data is also going to mailchimp but and I fill data in form which is published site then the data is not going to mailchimp?